# How to specify node version in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a Node project that I want to host on Heroku. I have explicitly defined node and npm versions in my package.json (located in the root directory), which looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "*********",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "**********",
 "engines": {
  "node": "8.x",
  "npm": "6.x"
 },
 "private": true,
 .....
 }
```

However, when I try to push the app to heroku. It still not read the node and npm version.

```
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use 
default)
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.4.1
```

Is there any solution for my case? Thank you anyway

Comment: I have to ask: are you entirely sure that the `package.json` you're showing us is the one you're pushing to Heroku?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is properly documented in [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version).

As you can see, the build log showed that there was no node version specified.

> engines.node (package.json):  unspecified

Your package.json is correct but you may not have your application set to use `heroku/nodejs` buildpack.

Use this to check what buildpack is being used.

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== issuetriage Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs

$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
Buildpack added. Next release on issuetriage will use heroku/nodejs.
Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.
```

If you post your full build log, it may be possible to discover something more.

Comment: Assuming OP is only using a single buildpack, `heroku/nodejs` should have been automatically detected via the `package.json` file. The build log clearly shows Node.js output, so this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 11):

I resolved this by adding engines in package.json file

```
"name": "myApp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"engines": {
    "node": "14.17.0",
    "npm": "6.14.13"
},
"main": "index.ts",
```

reference link :-https://help.heroku.com/6235QYN4/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-no-matching-node-versions

Comment: it worked for my rails project but before I had to add heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs -i 1